# Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have this error in my output screen, any idea what it means?

Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
    at soundboard_fla::MainTimeline/frame40()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at soundboard_fla::MainTimeline/onBirdsClick()

Comment: What's on frame 40 of soundboard.fla? Or even what is it doing?

Comment: add an eventlistener to the loader object for the IOErrorEvent event and it will go away

Answer (score 2):

Are you dynamically pulling in audio files or something like that?

I think that error means that you tried to load in an external file but that the URL is wrong, and that no file was found at that location. Double-check to make sure that any URLs you are pulling in are accurate!

Comment: Thankyou, that's really helpful. I'm not sure if you can help me, but what I'm trying to do is to get the movieclip to play the sound when it is dragged onto another movieclip and the play button is pressed so that the sounds are played in the order they are dragged on. I know I need to use an array and the push function and a loop...but I am lost. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just break it into parts: (1) A movie clip is dragged onto your player. (repeat (1) as necessary). (2) When your player receives that movieClip, it reads the audio URL from that movie clip and adds it to an array (let's call it "playBuffer"). So playBuffer[0] is your first URL, playBuffer[1] is your second, etc. (3) When someone presses play, you play the sounds. You could do something like: playBuffer.reverse(); while playBuffer.length > 0) { playSound(playBuffer.pop()) } or something to that effect. Make sense? Think in terms of concrete steps.

Comment: About that playBuffer.reverse() - that switches the order of the items in your array, so your first item becomes your last item. I'm doing that because pop() is an easy way to remove the last item from your array. So reverse makes your first item into your last item, then pop() returns and removes that item. This way you're guaranteed to step through in the same order that the URLs were added. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue twice now.  I am using PHP to pass XML data to a loader object.  Viewing of the PHP page and XML didn't lead me to the answer right away.  Everything looked fine.  XML was properly formatted.  Code APPEARED to be correct and, as stated, produced the correct XML.  What I ended up discovering is that I was cleaning up some variables in PHP at the end of my process, manual garbage collection.  A variable I had stopped using was still in the clean up process.  After removing the clean up process for that nonexistent variable, the error disappeared.  Long story short, don't delete variables you never declared.